# Array contains nulls PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have SQL query in PostgreSQL which filters particular fields in the form of an array
for being in bigint range. I would like to add the possibility not to filter out null values. With existing queries, null values for all of the fields are filtered out:

```
select *
from table_test
where '[0,2147483647]'::int8range @> ALL(ARRAY[fields])
```

And I would like to do something like this, only here I check against the whole array while I would want to check against each field:

```
select count(*) from dbm.inventory_source where '[0,2147483647]'::int8range @> ALL(ARRAY[id, exchange_id, min_cpm_micros])
or (array[id, exchange_id, min_cpm_micros]) is null
```

Also, I would not want to check each field for null instead I would like to check nulls for the whole array of fields.
I pass the names of the fields like one string into query (called fields) and it is the reason I do not want to check each field separately. Such implementation was created to have more generic queries for multiple tables.

How can I fix this query?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to add the possibility not to filter out null values.

Based on this, I would expect logic like:

```
where '[0,2147483647]'::int8range @> ALL(ARRAY[field_1, field_2, field_3]) or
      (field_1 is null and field_2 is null and field_3 is null)
```

I am unclear if you want to allow *all* values to be `NULL` or *any* of them.  The above is for *all* of them.  If you want any, change the `and`s to `or`s.

Comment: I have edited my question. I would not want to filter each field separately as it produces a lot of code changes

Comment: @Cassie . . . I actually fail to see the significant different between using `array[]` with a bunch of column names or adding `is null and/or` or each name.  Yes, the second is a little bit longer but not significantly so.

Comment: I can not use each field name specifically, because I pass all the field names as a single string in the code. And the fields string change for each table. There is a difference not in query length but in the fact that specifying each field is not generic, considering that this query is not used for one table only as I already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, presumably you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_test
WHERE '[0,2147483647]'::int8range @> ALL(ARRAY[fields]) IS NOT FALSE
```

(yeah, sorry, all I did was add three words and capitalize your keywords)

---

### What's this doing? Let's start from the top.

Let's look at what we want from all the conditional stuff. Specifically, it seems we want the condition to return `TRUE` for every array wherein *each* value of the array satisfies one of these two conditions:

1. The value falls within the range `[0,2147483647]`
2. The value is `NULL`

It's useful here to keep in mind the exact meaning of `NULL` in SQL: it's a value that we don't know. This is why `NULL` propagates in most operations, and thinking of it that way makes it easier to predict how the database will treat it. In fact, let's replace it with `?` for some examples. Why doesn't `? = ?` return `TRUE`? It's because we don't know what either of those values are, so we don't know if they're equal, so the expression evaluates to some unknown value, `NULL`. What about something like `? + 1`? Well, we don't know what the sum is, so it's also `NULL`. Similarly, `? AND TRUE` depends entirely on what the first value is, and we don't know what it is, so we write `NULL`.

This is where it gets fun: `? AND FALSE` will always be false, no matter what our unknown value is, so it evaluates to `FALSE` instead of `NULL`. Similarly, `? OR TRUE` must evaluate to `TRUE`.

Now, revisiting our two conditions, we see that your code already checked for condition 1. What about condition 2? Well, think about how `ALL` works, and what it's really telling you. It's basically evaluating your condition for each entry in your array, then combining all of those with `AND` to tell you whether or not it's true for all of the entries. This means that your test, specifically the expression

```
'[0,2147483647]'::int8range @> ALL(ARRAY[fields])
```

returns `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NULL` for *each* of the entries in the array, then combines those results using `AND`. Since we know that

1. `TRUE AND TRUE` returns `TRUE`
2. `NULL AND TRUE` returns `NULL`
3. `x AND FALSE` returns `FALSE` for any `x`

we can safely say that your code will return `FALSE` *if and only if* the array contains a value outside of your given range; otherwise, it will return `TRUE` or `NULL`. On the other hand, we want to get `TRUE` regardless of whether your code says `TRUE` or `NULL`; in other words, whenever it evaluates to anything other than `FALSE`. Luckily, [there's a predicate for that](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-comparison.html):

```
IS NOT NULL
```

Well! That was pretty complicated to think about, but after finding the solution, it seems almost offensively simple! Way to make me feel stupid.

Check it out [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iSiBCu6k2qf8mMTE9ddUNX/8).